# Why this s.e.s. splits?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

Suppose that $$0\to(M/N)^+\to M^+\to N^+\to 0$$

is a short exact sequence of modules with $(M/N)^+$ and $N^+$ injective
as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module).

Why $(M/N)^+\to M^+$ splits and what does it mean that it splits?

Comment: Every sequence $0\to L\to M\to N\to0$ with $L$ injective splits. This means that the map $L\to M$ has a left inverse or, equivalently, that the map $M\to N$ has a right inverse. In particular, these (one-sided) inverses, provide for an isomorphism $M\cong L\oplus N$.

Comment: @egreg How do I get the left inverese from the fact that $L$ is injective ? I wouldn't ask if things were so easy for me.

Comment: That's basically the definition of injective module. Consider the diagram in the Wikipedia page with $X=L$, $Y=M$, $f$ the given map, $Q=L$ and $g$ the identity. Then $h$ is the required left inverse to $f$.

Comment: @egreg Have we ever used that **both** $(M/N)^+$ and $N^+$ are injective ? It seems that you have **only** used that $(M/N)^+$ is injective, but [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499493/composition-of-flat-morphisms-is-flat) I was made to use a complicated argument that also $N^+$ is injective.

Comment: I see no mention of injective modules in the linked page. If $0\to L\to M\to N\to0$ is exact and $L$ is injective, then the sequence splits. If also $N$ is injective, then $M$ is injective as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might say the most "trivial" short exact sequence one could ask for is one of the form $0\to L\to L\oplus N\to N\to 0$, where the first map is the inclusion $x\mapsto(x,0)$ and the second map is the projection $(x,y)\mapsto y$. To say an arbitrary short exact sequence $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$ splits is a way of saying that it "looks like" one of these trivial exact sequences; more precisely, the sequence splits if there is an isomorphism $\theta:M\to L\oplus N$ making the following diagram commute

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>> L @>>> M@>>>N@>>>0 \\
    & @V{\mathrm{id}_L} V V @V{\theta} V V @V{\mathrm{id}_N} V V \\
    0 @>>> L @>>>L\oplus N@>>>N@>>>0
\end{CD}

Now it is a theorem, which you can find in just about any textbook discussing split exact sequences, that the sequence $0\to L\overset{\varphi}{\to} M\to N\to 0$ splits if and only if there is a homomorphism $r:M\to L$ such that $r\circ\varphi=\mathrm{id}_L$. Recreating the proof here would be pointless in my opinion, so either look it up or accept it as a black box for the time being; one place to look is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma).

From here, reexamine the definition of $L$ being an injective module: let's take for instance the third definition on the Wikipedia page you've linked. Then because $L$ is injective and $\varphi:L\to M$ is an injective module homomorphism and $\mathrm{id}_L:L\to L$ is a module homomorphism, the definition says there is a homomorphism $r:M\to L$ such that $r\circ\varphi=\mathrm{id}_L$, and this is exactly the criteria for the sequence to split.