# Composition of flat morphisms is flat

Tags: category-theory, modules, flatness, morphism, diagram-chasing

I do not understand in the snippet below why the composition of flat morphisms is flat. The full text (though in Czech) is given [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/~rosicky/lectures/algebra3.pdf).
I do not understand these step given in **bold**, beginning from $q\cdot u=0$ **implies**
$q\cdot p_2\cdot g=0$, **so** $q \cdot p_2\cdot g=0$ **so** $q\cdot p_2=h\cdot p_3$ **for some $h$**.
 **Then** $$h\cdot v \cdot p_2=h\cdot p_3=q\cdot p_2$$ **then** $h\cdot v=q$.
[image]

Comment: I think you're more likely to get a response if you just translate the whole argument into English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, after we have proven that $u$ is injective, we want to realise $C/A$ as an extension of flat modules $B/A$ and $C/B$. To this end, we first prove that $u$ is injective and then consider the quotient map $q\colon C/A\to C/B$. As $q\circ u= 0$ by construction, $0= q\circ u\circ p_1 = q\circ p_2\circ g$. Therefore $q\circ p_2$ vanishes on the image of $B$ in $C$ under the inclusion $g$ and hence factorises through $C/B$, so $q\circ p_2 = h\circ p_3$ for some $h\colon C/B\to C/B$.

Now, $h\circ v\circ p_2 = h\circ p_3 = q\circ p_2$. As $p_2$ is an epimorphism, it can be cancelled if it is the rightmost morphism, so $h\circ v = q$. This realises $C/A$ as an extension of flat modules $B/A\to C/A\to C/B$ with the inclusion map $u$ and the quotient map $q$.

Comment: I'm trying to orient myself in your arguments. $p_2$ is a projection, how this implies it is an epimorphism ? Is every projection an epi ? Can you type $\to$ into your last sentence so that I understand what is an extension and what is a quotient ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, in every concrete category (one whose underlying objects are sets) every morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ which is surjective on the level of sets is an epimorphism. Indeed, if $g_1\circ f = g_2\circ f$, then $g_1$ and $g_2$ coincide on the image of $f$ which is by assumption the whole of $Y$, so $g_1 = g_2$.

Comment: How do we need $h\circ v=q$ to see that the inclusion map is $u$ and the quotient map is $q$ ?

Comment: Well, $q$ is by construction the quotient map associated to the injection $u$, but we want to deduce that this very quotient coincides with $C/g(B)$ which we know is flat. This is achieved by factoring $q$ as $h\circ v$ which maps to $C/g(B)$ by construction.

Comment: There is a typo here: what we want to deduce is that $C/A$ (more pedantically, $C/g\circ f(A)$ is flat as the claim is that the composition $g\circ f$ of two flat inclusions is flat.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly is the typo. In your comments, answer or snippet in the Czech ?

Comment: In the snippet: the last sentence of the proof should claim that $C/A$ is flat, not $B/A$.

Comment: I do not follow one more detail. How factoring $q$ as $h\circ v$ helps us ? Shouldn't $q$ be $g$ somewhere?

Comment: Well, from the definition of $q$ it doesn't a priori follow that the quotient is isomorphic $C/g(B)$ of which we know that it's flat. To see that this is the case one needs this factorisation.

Comment: What I do not understand is that $g$ **never appears** in this sentence: "$q$ factorizes as $h\circ v$" .

Comment: It does in a way: $C/B$ has to be read as $C/g(B)$, so all these morphisms act on modules constructed with the use of $g$.

Comment: One small detail yet: from where do we know that $(u,v)$ in the Czech snippet is a short exact sequence? Once we know that we can use the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496527/why-this-s-e-s-splits) `Jan 3 20:41` to see that $C/A$ is flat from the fact that $C/B$ is flat, right ?

Comment: I think that formally speaking the proof uses $(u,q)$ as the short exact sequence instead.I also think that the way the proof is written is actually unnecessarily complicated: a) there is no need to discuss amalgamated products because one can directly show that $u$ is injective: it is induced by the map $g$, and if $g(b) \in g(f(A))$, then $b\in f(A)$ by injectivity of $g$; b) one can indeed show directly that $v$ is the quotient map corresponding to $u$. Indeed, $v$ is induced by the injection $f\colon A\to B$, so it is automatically surjective, and its kernel coincides with $[g(B)]=u(B/A)$.

Comment: So in the end you're right: one could use $(u,v)$ as the short exact sequence which makes things work.

Comment: How do we know that the **entire** diagram in the snippet commutes ?

Comment: Well, both parts (the 4-gon and the triangle) commute by construction, so the whole thing commutes.